# Links are moving on hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am making a dropdown menu with css. But when i hover on my link then the sublinks fadein. That works, But right after it Faded in the links go like 1px to the left and The sublinkbar is 1px larger.
html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <title>..</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="Main-Wrapper">
            <div id="Nav-Bar">
                <div id="Nav-Bar-LinkContainer">
                    <div id="nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Voorstellingen</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Voorstelling 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Voorstelling 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Voorstelling 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Voorstelling 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">The locals</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Speellijst</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Boekingen</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <a href=""><img src="images/YouTube.png" id="Social1"></a>
                    <a href=""><img src="images/Facebook.png" id="Social2"></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="Main-Container">
                <div id="Main-Content">



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The css:

```
@font-face { font-family: kop; src: url('Viafont.ttf'); }
#Main-Wrapper {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
#Nav-Bar {
    background-color: #E6F9FF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E6E6E6;
}
#Nav-Bar-LinkContainer {
    height: 70px;
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
    z-index: 4;
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#nav li {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 23px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
}
#nav ul li {
    width: 200px;
}
#nav ul {
    margin-top: 10px;
    opacity: 0.0;   
    width: 0px;
    transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
    position:absolute;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.ie_does_hover ul {
    opacity: 1.0;
    left: auto;

}
#nav li a {
    text-align: center;
    width: 159px;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 5px 3px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: kop;
    font-size: 1.0em;
}
#nav ul li a {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    width: 195px;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 5px 3px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: kop;
    font-size: 1.0em;
}
div a{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #535353;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:color 0.4s;
}
div ul a:link, div ul a:visited{
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #FF6600;
}
div ul li{
    background-color: #666;
}
* html ul li, * html div ul li{
border-bottom: 3px solid #FFF;
}
* html div ul li{
border-top: 0;
}
#Main-Container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#Main-Content {
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1100px;
    margin:  0 auto 0 auto;
}
#Social1 {
    width: 35px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
#Social2 {
    width: 35px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#Social2:hover,#Social1:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I also got a standard reset.css
Can one of you see the problem?

Comment: `margin: 2px 5px 3px 5px;`.  Could it be that they are moving 3px to the right (not 1px)?  You have the `left:auto;' on hover as well.

Comment: I'm not noticing anything here on Chrome/Win7: http://jsfiddle.net/8ADYT/

Comment: Hey, thank you for your fast response! I removed both of the margins and it worked for what i asked but it made an new problem :( Now my links in my subbar is going down like 1px (can be 2 or 3 too but not 5). Fixed that left but doesnt help anything at the problem. At jsfiddle there is indeed no problem. On my pc with Chrome/win7 I have the problem

Comment: Can you include your fiddle?